# Installing SugarCRM On Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crm, sugarcrm

I need a stellar guide to installing SugarCRM On Ubuntu, can anyone recommend a website or a document to doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try [Bitnami's installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/sugarcrm)? They're supposed to be as easy as possible.

Comment: Loading outside VM's are not supported by my VPS.

Comment: Use the native installer: http://bitnami.org/files/stacks/sugarcrm/bitnami-sugarcrm-5.2.0j-0-linux-installer.bin

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few sites I have found:

- [ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-sugarcrm-community-edition-in-ubuntu-810-server.html)
- [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-sugarcrm-community-edition-on-ubuntu-8.10)